# iOS arm64 project with 32 bit third party library

Tags: ios, objective-c, arm64

As you may know, 1 February 2015 apple pushes us to build projects both 64 and 32 bit supports. However, our projects use third party library which does not include arm64 slice. Is there any way that i can add exception for 32 bit library to build project as arm64.

For example: iOS projects that use ARC system can make exception for single file which does not use ARC system by settings compiler flags with -fno-objc-arc.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is quite simple: unfortunately no. To have a 64-bit binary app you have to recompile all thirdy part libraries used in your project.
This mean that if you don't have the source code of these libraries and the authors didn't release a 64-bit version of the lib, your app will never been compliant for 64-bit requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Also i opened ticket and they also gave same answer. Thanks again